# Remove smooth scroll animation on changing page in NextJS with Link component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Don't know if it's a new feature of nextJS, because i don't have this problem with my previous nextJs project but when i'm on the bottom of a page and i want to go to another page, it's appear a scroll to top on the destination page.

I want to go on the destination page, at the top, but without this "smooth scroll" animation.

( i don't have any smooth behavior in my css )

In NextJs docs they say you can remove the scroll by putting scroll to false, but if i do that , when i reach my destination page, i will be at the bottom of the destination page ( if when i click on my start page i was on the bottom )

**my app file :**

```
import '../styles/main.scss'

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}

export default MyApp
```

**how i declare my Link component and nav in Layout** :

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import Link from "next/link";
import Nav from "./shared/nav";
import { useEffect } from "react";

export default function Layout({ children, page }) {
  const router = useRouter();
  {/* https://css-tricks.com/transitions-only-after-page-load/ */ }
  useEffect(() => { document.querySelector("body").classList.add("preload") });

  return (
    <>
  <Head>

    <title>{page}</title>
    
  </Head>

  <header>
    <Nav />
  </header>

  <main>
    {children}
  </main>

  <TopFooter />
  <div className="wrapper mx-auto">
    <footer className="pb-md-7 pb-6">
      <div className="row mt-7">
        <nav className="col-xs-11 col-xsm-11 col-sm px-lg-0 pt-md-0 pt-3">
          <ul className="navbar mt-lg-3 ps-xs-0 px-sm-0">
            <li className="pe-sm-0 ">
              <Link href="/legal/aml-kyc-policy">
                <a>AML/KYC
                  policy</a>
              </Link>
            </li>
            <li className="pe-sm-0 ps-xsm-0 legalMention">
              <Link href="/legal/mentions">
                <a>Legal
                  Mention</a>
              </Link>
            </li>
            <li className="pe-sm-0 ps-xsm-0 pt-1 pt-sm-0">
              <Link href="/legal/privacy-policy">
                <a>Privacy
                  Policy</a>
              </Link>
            </li>
            <li className="pe-sm-0 ps-xsm-0 pt-1 pt-sm-0">
              <Link href="/legal/cookies-policy">
                <a>Cookies Policy</a>
              </Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
      <script> </script>
    </footer>

  </div>
</>
  );
}
```

Can somoene help me fix this ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Which browser are you using? In Firefox, smooth scrolling needs to be disabled in `about:preferences`

Comment: hello, i'm using chrome. But i think this matter need to be fixe with some code , not with brower preference @brc-dd

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you could set this globally by targeting either (A) the root id or (b) the body of the entire app directly.
`scroll-behavior: smooth` (nextjs uses this for its link component)
try
`scroll-behavior: auto !important`

For example, in my global css File I target the `#__next` id:

```css
  #__next {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 100vh;
  }
```

I also target the `html` and `body` tags:

```css
  html {
    height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    touch-action: manipulation;
    font-feature-settings: 'case' 1, 'rlig' 1, 'calt' 0;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;

    /* -webkit-text-size-adjust: none; */
    /* text-size-adjust: none; */
  }

  html,
  body {
    font-family: var(--font-sans);
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    background-color: var(--theme-0);
    color: var(--text-accents-0);
    overscroll-behavior-x: contain;
  }
```

I would recommend using one of these to inject something like

```css
a:link { 
    scroll-behavior: auto !important;
}
```

to remove the smooth scroll behavior from `<a></a>` with links embedded (your Link component ultimately compiles down to `<a></a>` tags in the browser)

Comment: hello , i will try this one thanks a lot for your time and answer

Comment: ok thanks a lot Andrew , with only this one 

`html {  scroll-behavior: auto !important;}`

i remove smooth scroll behavior . Thanks a lot !!!!

Answer (score 1):

For mine because I use NextJs with Bootstrap, I found out that when I disable the bootstrap, it works well, what I found later on, i just have to add scroll behavior to auto.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).